# bitsadmin.exe running in the background

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently developing a script using batch and python to complement it and I want to download files using bitsadmin.exe but when I do, it opens a "cmd" and I need it to be "silent", not popping that window...

I tried to use

```
@echo off

start "" bitsadmin.exe /transfer "name" (url) (destination)
```

But it's no use.. Any help?

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: you forgot to explain why you need `start ""` in the first place.  Why can't you just directly invoke `bitsadmin.exe` without `start` ?

Comment: I use start "" because like that it won't pop the window,

eg.
start "" taskkill /f /im pythonw.exe

Comment: Batch can't run things in the background.

Comment: `start "" [/WAIT] /MIN ...`?

Answer (score 1):

As @SomethingDark said, we cannot hide a program directly from a batch script. So, you'll need to add some VBScript.

Try this VBS(Save it as Script.**vbs**):

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c bitsadmin.exe /transfer "name" (url) (destination)", 0, True
```

---

Then call it from the batch file:

```
@echo off
REM your script......

cscript //nologo Script.vbs
REM The command above will do the bitsadmin thingy.
```

I assumed you named the VBS as **Script.vbs**, you can change <kbd>Script.vbs</kbd> to whatever name your script is.

Comment: That just minimizes the window, I wanted it to run in the background

Comment: As @SomethingDark say, you can't run something in the background using batch, switch to VBS for that. The `/min` is the closest way to get on pure batch

Comment: VBS solution added.

Comment: This didnt work for me...